# How to use Struts 2 Token Tag correctly in a distributed Java environment?

Tags: struts2, token, distributed, csrf

Struts 2 support stop double-submission of forms by generate a unique random token and store it in the session, and use token tag pass the token to the client form then verify the tokens from session and form.

As far as i know, this solution can only work in a single JVM because the session is separated from each other. I cannot find something useful about how to use this solution in a distributed Java environment. We use Nginx proxy HTTP requests to multiple JVMs and Nginx does not guarantee to proxy the same request to the same JVM every time.

Can someone give me some help?

BTW, i am trying to use this solution to stop CSRF attack.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices (neither of which really has anything to do with Struts 2, but has everything to do with session management in a distributed environment):

1. Use Session Affinity - so when a user creates a session, Nginx remembers which backend server the user went to, and that session is bound to that server for all subsequent requests. [(This is the more typical solution)](https://serverfault.com/questions/405331/sticky-sessions-based-on-a-cookie-using-nginx). might get you started.
2. Depending on your application server, there may be the possibility of sharing the session data between servers. For example, in Tomcat 6, [the configuration directions are](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html).

Comment: 1) Using session affinity can cause problems when re-deploy or restart one of the application servers, 2) distributed session is complex and i don't prefer this and 3) i consider to use memcached to replace distributed session.

Comment: Since Struts 2 already support this in some degree, i am trying to use it.

Comment: If you store your sessions in memcache, then the session (with the token in it) will be available to all of the Tomcat servers and this wont be an issue.